# Python: Capturing high collinearity in statsmodel (regression) for panel data

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, regression, statsmodels

I was trying to solve a problem that asked me to assess whether the digital advertising campaign is successful in driving volume sales.

Because we only have limited impression data, I have filled 0 in impression for those that are nan.

The data is on a weekly basis and it looks like this:
[image]

Then I did a scatterplot for impression and volume:
[image]

However when I try to regression using impression as x and volume as y in statsmodel it gives me collinearity warning but I 'm only using impression as x variables. The code I'm using is the following:
[image]

And it gives me the following result:
[image]
[image]

Could anyone help me to figure out?? Is my approach wrong? I'm really confused since I only have one x, there shouldn't be any collinearity. Should I be concerned that because it is a panel data that I should use other approaches? Any suggestion is appreciated, thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

see for example https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/332428/regression-model-constant-causes-multicollinearity-warning-but-not-in-standardi/332597#332597

Statsmodels computes the condition number of the design matrix and it is therefore sensitive to the scaling of the explanatory variables.
The main interest in computing the condition number this way is to indicate whether there are possible numerical problems with the actual design matrix and not so much as a diagnostic indicator for multicollinearity. Statsmodels takes the user provided design matrix as given and does not standardize or transform the design matrix to improve numerical stability.

In this example there is no multicollinearity, but the scale of `Impression` is much larger than the constant coded as 1.

Also, the regression coefficient is very small to compensate for the large scale of the explanatory variable.

So, both numerical stability and interpretation of the parameter would be improved by rescaling the `Impression` variable, for example by using 100,000 as the unit of `Impression`.